# What is secure false in crossdomain.xml used for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, crossdomain.xml

We are uploading files from an HTTP uri scheme to our S3. This means, our uploader script is in our server. We sign the forms accordingly with S3. Our crossdomain.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Should I have `secure="false"` in `allow-access-from`? For example:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
```

What are the implications of having `secure="false"`? I've read [this](http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html#allow-access-from-secure) and [this](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/oct/the-crossdomain.xml-witch-hunt), but don't quite understand it properly.

Second, should `domain=*` be an actual domain? i.e. our domain name? So http://foobar.com and http://www.foobar.com?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you have `secure="true"` only requests from HTTPS will be allowed, `secure="false"` mean requests from both HTTP and HTTPS are allowed.

EDIT: it only applies if you are running HTTPS website. E.g. if http://website1.com requests for a resource from website https://website2.com, which has a `secure="true"` in the crossdomain.XML, then the resource will be denied. However if website 2 is running on HTTP and not HTTPS, then it doesn't matter and both HTTP and HTTPS will be permitted, no matter what the secure setting in crossdomain.xml says.

http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/crossdomain/policyfiles.html#allow-access-from-secure

Comment: I tried both actually. I am still able to upload with `secure="true"` and `secure="false"` from HTTP. Why is it allowing me to upload from HTTP if `secure="true"` is set?